# Change x-y cordinate starting position in leaflet.js custom maps

Tags: leaflet

How to change the x-y axis starting point from bottom left corner to top left corner in leaflet.js custom maps?By default it is at bottom left corner..

Comment: The "origin pixel" is located at the top left corner ([see Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-getpixelorigin)).  Other methods (e.g., `layerPointToLatLng(<Point> point)` and
`latLngToLayerPoint(<LatLng> latlng)`) are evaluated with respect to that origin pixel.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Leaflet.js origin start with Bottom-Left for custom map (http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) , I need to start origin from top - left corner of image. Thanks for your help

Comment: Okay, see edited answer below.

Answer (score 2):

For a standard map, the top left corner is the origin, as is explained [here in the Leaflet tutorials](http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html):

> When the L.Map is ready (has a center LatLng and a zoom level), the absolute pixel coordinates of the top-left corner become the “pixel origin”
>   [image]

---

**EDIT:** As OP pointed out, [`L.CRS.Simple` has the origin in the bottom left corner](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#crs-l-crs-simple).

> A simple CRS that maps longitude and latitude into x and y directly. May be used for maps of flat surfaces (e.g. game maps). Note that the y axis should still be inverted (going from bottom to top).

To change this behavior, edit the `leaflet-src.js` document (or the minified version) to change the transformation:

```
L.CRS.Simple = L.extend({}, L.CRS, {
  projection: L.Projection.LonLat,
  transformation: new L.Transformation(1, 0, 1, 0), // this line is changed!!
  ... // more leaflet variables
}
```

Here's a screen shot of crs-simple-example2.html (from [the official tutorial examples](http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html)) implemented with the old (left) and new (right) coordinate transformations.

[image]